# How to save the downloaded file to a folder

Tags: php, curl, simple-html-dom

I write a parser receiving video.No can`t save the resulting video itself to the desired folder to me. How to fix, here's the code.

```
foreach ($href as $key => $link) {
    $doc = file_get_html('https://example.com/'.$link);
    foreach($doc->find("#video source") as $el) {
        $video[]="https:".$el->src;   
    }
}
//finally I get
/* array(
    "http:example/video1.mp4",
    "http:example/video2.mp4",
    "http:example/video3.mp4")
 */

$dirSubtitles=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/video/';
foreach ($video as $key=>$address) {
    $url  = $address;
    $path = $dirSubtitles;
    $fp = fopen($path."video".$key, 'w');
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: you never DO anything with `$data`. you just do a curl and keep overwriting it. Where's your file saving code?

Comment: @MarcB In the array of video I have links leading to video.S using curl, I'm trying to save what was found to the address

Comment: you're not trying to do anything. `$data` would be whatever the url you curl'd produced. if you want that data saved, then you have to do something to make that data be written to disk, e.g. file_put_contents() or whatever.

Comment: @MarcB I'm trying to save data using fopen in foreach

Comment: ah yes. apologies... then did you check if your urls are actually working? `http:example` is NOT a valid url... if curl_exec() fails, it returns boolean false. you never check for that either. `if ($data === false) { die(curl_error($ch)); }` etc...

Comment: @MarcB this abstract url ,the real me does not. Real url that I have it it is valid so I print the array it was trying to go

Comment: I don't see any code writing to the file you opened?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read about [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

I hope this will help you in the right direction.